# wordpress not getting current image path in css

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am developing my first plugin in wordpress and using `background-image` in style tag:

```
<head>
<style>
    .remove {
        border: solid;
        background-image: url(icon-remove.jpg);
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: block;
        font-size: 14px;
        height: 20px;
        padding-top: 40px;
        text-align: center !important;
    }
</style>
</head>
```

My plugin path is:

```
..www/wpsample/wp-content/plugins/sample
```

The Image file is present in same directory (/sample)

but it showing me error in console as 404 and the path it is looking for is

```
http://localhost/wpsample/wp-admin/icon-remove.jpg
```

How do I specify correct path for image file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying many solution finally this works for me

```
background-image: url("<?php echo plugins_url().'/sample/icon-remove.jpg'?>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the wp_enqueue_style command to tell WP where the file is:

```
   wp_enqueue_style('myStyle' //--- name
       //--- location of css file relative to this file
      , plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'css/myCSS.css'
      , array()
   );
```

This is required because people can install WP and set the folders to different names. The wp_enqueue_style will handle this for you.

Alternatively, embed the CSS within the same file.

Comment: Hi, this include css file in script. I want to give image path for  background-image:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `background-image` in wordpress plugin, You should use relative css path to the stylesheet. Example:

```
background-image: url("../wp-content/plugins/sample/icon-remove.jpg");
```

Or you can add full url in `url()`:

```
background-image: url("http://localhost/wpsample/wp-content/plugins/sample/icon-remove.jpg");
```

For more information read this link: [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri)

Comment: i have tried both the solution first one create path as `http://localhost/wpsample/wp-admin/wp-content/plugins/sample/icon-remove.jpg` it goes in 'wp-admin' dir first then check for 'wp-content' which is wrong path . second one works fine but as it is an plugin it is going on multiple location so i can not put static path

Comment: @ParitoshMahale I edited my answer, please try again and use this url path: `../wp-content/plugins/sample/icon-remove.jpg`

Comment: thank you for response it works fine using `background-image: url("<?php echo plugins_url().'/sample/icon-remove.jpg'?>");`